# Check if a HTTP request returns 404 or page not found

Tags: wordpress, function, http

I'm searching for a function that tells me if an URL returns a `404` HTTP error or "Page not found" inside WordPress.

Could be something like `is_404($url)`, but this function works without parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possibile achieve that using [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php).

**EDIT**

Add this to your functions.php:

```
function wpcf_is_404( $url = null ){
    $code = '';
    if( is_null( $url ) ){
        return false;
    }else{
        $handle = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_exec($handle);
        $code = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if( $code == '404' ){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        curl_close($handle);
    }
}
```

and then make a call to `wpcf_is_404();` in your template files or in your functions.php to test if the given url returns true ( 404 ) or false ( all other responses )
Hope it helps!